# Is there a saying in Sanskrit scripture that Narada's mischiefs always end well?

Tags: narada

There is a Tamil saying நாரதர் கலகம் நன்மையில் முடியும்

"Narada's mischif-making always ends well"

Is there a similar saying in Sanskrit scripture and would that be true of all of Narada's interventions?